# SVD on Correlation Matrix

Tags: eigenvalues-eigenvectors, svd

By doing some numerical examples I have satisfied myslef that the left and right singular vectors are equal for such matrices.

http://people.revoledu.com/kardi/tutorial/LinearAlgebra/SVD.html

However I would like to see a proof of this mathematically.

Also it seems to contradict the definintion given here:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singular_value_decomposition

which says that:

"Non-degenerate singular values always have unique left- and right-singular vectors, up to multiplication by a unit-phase factor eiφ (for the real case up to sign). Consequently, if all singular values of M are non-degenerate and non-zero, then its singular value decomposition is unique, up to multiplication of a column of U by a unit-phase factor and simultaneous multiplication of the corresponding column of V by the same unit-phase factor."

So how come for a correlation matrix the svd can have equal right and left singular vectors without becoming degenerate?

Baz

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because a correlation matrix is symmetric , the right- and leftmultiplication to SVD/diagonalization are just the transposes of each other. Note, that "unique" does not mean *"each one is different"* here, but rather: we'll *"unambiguously find a definitive solution"* for the right- as well for the leftmultiplication.

Answer (score 1):

The finite-dimensional version of the "spectral theorem" says every real symmetric matrix can be diagonalized by an orthogonal matrix.  The singular value decomposition says every real matrix can be diagonalized by *two* orthogonal matrices.  When it's symmetric, you get only one of them.  It appears on the left and its transpose on the right.